# Compare number of elements in Set & List

Tags: apex, controller, list, set

How to compare whether number of elements in a List & a set is same or not? Can someone please let me know? Not getting it for set directly except traversing in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the size() method on the List and Set to get the number of elements.

```
List<String> aList = new List<String> { 'a', 'b', 'b' };  
Set<String> aSet = new Set<String> { 'a', 'b', 'c' };  

Boolean sameSize = (aList.size() == aSet.size());  
System.debug('sameSize ? ' + sameSize);
```

Comment: Are two duplicate elements in a set counted as two elements when we use size() method?